# What is the difference between starting a block of code in CSS by . [dot] and by # [hash]?

Tags: html, css, web, stylesheet

Please answer the following questions for the two CSS example codes given in the end.

1. What is the difference between the two codes? One is starting with dot and one with hash.
2. How can I call these styles into HTML? Should I use
   `class="searchwrapper"`  or should I use `id="searchwrapper"` ? And why, what is the difference?

Example 1: Starting with #[hash]

```
#searchwrapper {
    /*some text goes here*/
}
```

Example 2: Starting with .[dot]

```
.searchbox {
    /*some text goes here*/
}
```

Answer (score 23):

## The Difference:

`.` specifies a class

`#` specifies an ID

**Class Example:**

```
.myElement {...}
```

will match

```
<div class="myElement">
```

**ID Example:**

```
#myElement {...}
```

will match

```
<div id="myElement">
```

## Class or ID: How to choose

Only one element may have a particular ID, but multiple elements may share a particular class.

- If you target one specific element, give that element an ID and use `#` in your CSS.
- If you target multiple related elements, give them a class and use `.` in your CSS.

Comment: What is the benefit of using hash over dot?

Comment: @iSumitG: See the updated answer for an explanation of when to use each.

Answer (score 6):

These are CSS selectors:

- `#foo` means an element with id `foo`
- `.foo` means all element with class `foo`

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

IDs are unique, so you can only have one element with the same ID. While a class can be the same for many elements (and every element can have several classes).

Comment: What if I write like this: div.searchwrapper {/*something*/}

Comment: That would be a div element with the class `searchWrapper`.

Comment: @iSumitG, that would match all `div`s which have the class `searchwrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

1. [dot] is a class selector, see [Id Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors)
2. # is an id selector, see [Class Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html)

Comment: Is there a benefit over one another?

Comment: @ramono: yep, confused a bit ;)

Comment: @iSumitG, you use id's for elements that shall be identified by a unique name. No two elements on one page can have the same id. However, theoretically, you can have an unlimited number of elements all with the same class. An example of using an id would be to identify a logo. An example of using a class would be to identify anybody's profile picture on say Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

"#" is used if you have assigned id to the document element and "." dot is used if you have used class with the document element.

Id for each element on an document is unique, so if you use # means you want to apply to only that element.

Where as if you use "." dot , it means you want to apply css to the elements whose class attirbute is set to that name which is after dot in css. like ".myClass" so myClass is the class name.

You can you can apply same css on multiple ids by :

```
#id1,#id2{
//your css
}
```

Comment: CSS doesn't have one line comments (which is annoying). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

These are CSS selectors:

`#foo` means an element with id set to foo, it refers to `<div id="foo">`
`.foo` means an element with class foo, it refers to `<div class="foo">`

Plus: you can have several elements with the same `class` but you can't have more than one with the same ìd`. (Actually you can but it's BAD, and W3C will punish you).

Answer (score 1):

'.' is  class selector and it can apply on multiple element which have same class

'#' is  id selector and only apply on particular one element Id